# Pexpect is not working as expected. Its not returning the correct output on virtual machines

Tags: python, virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.04, pexpect

[NOTE: I have run this code in the physical machine, it works(OS=Fedora 14). But when i used the same script in the Ubuntu instlled on the Virtual machine, it does not work. I am trying to capture the ifconfig output and save/print it.]

I have installed Ubuntu on the VMPlayer (it is virtual machine). I am using python scripting language and trying to automate the SSH connection using Pexpect. I am running the script on the same Ubuntu Virtual Machine. Given below is the of the things that I am doing with this script:

1. Using Pexpect, connect to the localhost over SSH
2. execute "ifconfig" cli command and capture the output.
3. print this cli output.

## Code Snippet:

```
  class Linux:
    HOSTIP      =    ""
    USER        =    ""
    PASSWD      =    ""
    HOST        =    ""

    PROMPTTIMEOUT =    120
    PROMPT        =    ""
    ERRORFLAG     =    False
    ERRORMSG      =    ""
    CLIOUTPUT     =    ""


    def __init__(self,host, user, passwd, prompt):
        self.HOSTIP    =    host
        self.USER      =    user
        self.PASSWD    =    passwd
        self.PROMPT    =    prompt
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        try:
            connection   =    "ssh " + self.USER + "@" + self.HOSTIP
            self.HOST    =    pexpect.spawn(connection)
            while 1:
                returnNum    =    self.HOST.expect(["yes/no","password:"],120)
                if returnNum == 0:
                    self.HOST.send("yes\r\n")        
                elif returnNum == 1:
                    self.HOST.send(self.PASSWD + "\r\n")
                    break
            self.HOST.expect(self.PROMPT,120)
            self.CLIOUTPUT  =       self.HOST.before                        
            self.HOST.send("\r\n")
            self.HOST.expect(self.PROMPT,120)
            self.CLIOUTPUT  =       self.CLIOUTPUT + self.HOST.before
        except Exception:
            return False
        return True


    def executeCLI(self, cmd):
        self.resetErrors()
        try:
            self.HOST.send("\r\n")
            self.HOST.expect(self.PROMPT,120)
            self.HOST.send(cmd + "\r\n")
            self.HOST.expect(self.PROMPT,120)

            self.CLIOUTPUT     =    self.HOST.before
            self.HOST.send("\r\n")
            self.HOST.expect(self.PROMPT,120)

            self.CLIOUTPUT    =    self.CLIOUTPUT + self.HOST.before
        except Exception:
            return False
            return True

    def getCLIOutput(self):
            return self.CLIOUTPUT

# Testing Class Linux.py                        

host    =    Linux("1.1.1.1", "admin", "admin123", "@ubuntu")
host.executeCLI("ifconfig")
print("Output : " + str(host.getCLIOutput()))
```

## Result Output:

```
admin@ubuntu12:/home/Host# python Linux.py
Output : 12: ~admin12:~$

admin@ubuntu12:/home/Host#
```

## Expected Output:

```
admin@ubuntu12:/home/Host# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:60:6b:be
          inet addr:192.168.2.5  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe60:6bbe/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1733 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1539 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:205502 (205.5 KB)  TX bytes:252126 (252.1 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2024

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:60:6b:c8
          inet addr:20.20.20.2  Bcast:20.20.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe60:6bc8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:82 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5132 (5.1 KB)  TX bytes:12322 (12.3 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0x20a4

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:27353 (27.3 KB)  TX bytes:27353 (27.3 KB)

admin@ubuntu12:/home/Host#
```

If I manually do the SSH login to the LOCALHOST and execute the IFCONFIG command at the CLI, then i am seeing the below output on the screen:

```
admin@ubuntu12:/home/Host# ssh admin@192.168.2.5
admin@192.168.2.5's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

67 packages can be updated.
35 updates are security updates.

Last login: Sat Sep 21 22:55:36 2013 from 192.168.2.5
admin@ubuntu12:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:60:6b:be
          inet addr:192.168.2.5  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe60:6bbe/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3664 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:463331 (463.3 KB)  TX bytes:625129 (625.1 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2024

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:60:6b:c8
          inet addr:20.20.20.2  Bcast:20.20.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe60:6bc8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:15340 (15.3 KB)  TX bytes:14388 (14.3 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0x20a4

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:192908 (192.9 KB)  TX bytes:192908 (192.9 KB)

admin@ubuntu12:~$
```

Comment: I assume you have a different ip than 1.1.1.1 in line host    =    Linux("1.1.1.1", "admin", "admin123", "@ubuntu")

Comment: @blueberryfields: Thanks for reply. There is no problem with the IP. I have changed the IP address to 1.1.1.1 while posting the code. Instead please use "localhost" instead.

Comment: It is working if i establish the connection & return the spawn_session id and use this spawn_session outside the class. Even if i try passing the spawn_session id in the executeCLI method and try to use inside the method to execute "ifocnfig" command. But it still doesn t work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all "\r\n" by "\n" and it would work